# Raspberry Pi Raspbian switching Multiple Desktops by application

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

I'm running Raspbian Pi v11 (bullseye), and I'm booting into the GUI. I'd like to set up two desktops that will run a single full-screen app on each (example: one is a web browser). And then via my custom software, I'd like to switch the active desktop on the fly, without user interaction.

Any suggestions on how this might be done? Thanks.

**EDIT**: I suppose that having both as full-screen applications on a single desktop and (in some way) switching between them would be an alternative, but I am not sure how to do that either.

Answer (score 0):

Most Linux OS come with a Desktop pager.

Simon Long's response to a support question "We’ve never supported desktop paging; it’s in there because it’s in LXDE, and we’ve never actually removed it, but it’s not something we will be supporting going forward, I’m afraid. If it doesn’t work with mutter – and it sounds as if it doesn’t – we are unlikely to have the time to fix it."

Try Buster.
If might work if you revert to Openbox.